# Testing security of IoT devices

Tags: security, testing

Searching the archives for "fuzz" and "pentest" only results in 2-3 relevant threads on this topic and they are all from 2016/2017.

I would really like to subject my IoT devices (e.g. surveillance cameras) to **severe testing** to uncover bugs and other security issues.

How would you advice a beginner in this field to perform such tests? I have a bit of experience in embedded programming (C, currently learning Rust), but have not really done any fuzzing before.

Comment: If your device is connected to an IP network, you probably want to start with penetration testing tools. Online versions may have a problem doing an exhaustive search if your device is on a network behind a NAT, though. https://security.stackexchange.com may be a better place for security-related questions.

Answer (score 5):

This really depends on how you are connecting to the IoT network in the first place. I am assuming you mean via TCP/IP.

Depending on how far you wish to go with this, you may want to look into a [bootable Kali Linux USB](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/kali-linux-live-usb-install/) to run the pentests. (Its literally what that OS was designed to do)

You can use Nmap in linux/Windows to determine ports that are open/answering on the LAN. (this will expose services that are answering to client probes.) it comes pre-installed in kali.

Once you have found open services/ports you can use something like [metasploit](https://www.metasploit.com/get-started) to try and exploit the vulnerabilities your devices may or may not have.

unfortunately explaining how to use these programs or operating systems is outside the scope of this question. I hope it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

### In *addition* of runtime testing....

You might **consider using [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) techniques**, e.g. with [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or [Clang analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). Read also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report for more, and consider using [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) after september 2020. See also  [Chariot](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) and [Decoder](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) and [Vessedia](https://vessedia.eu/) European projects.

Another approach would be a [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) approach : you would write (or use) your own C code generator from some higher level domain specific language (perhaps of your invention, but then read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/%7Escott/pragmatics/)). This has been used in [SWIG](https://swig.org/) and you could use tools like [Coq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq) to prove *some* safety properties (e.g. of your C code generator, or *sometimes and partly* of the generated C code)

If you compile your IoT code with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, consider writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to check *some* safety properties. Be of course aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) (and see also the ambitious [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) project).

Look also inside the [CompCert](http://compcert.inria.fr/) project.